# How to find a function which describes the system's potential energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, spring

I was wondering how to determine the potential energy of a certain system. Let's say I have three bars and three springs connected in a certain way, so that when the gravitational potential energy $U_g$ of the bars decreases, the elastic potential energy $U_e$ of the springs increases. Is it legit to say that

Utot = 3Ug + 3Ue

Comment: This is a bit general. It is like asking about a recipe to make food. The answer would be a textbook on mechanics. You might start here for an overview of the ideas. [Mechanics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/index.html#mechcon)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not legit. Take the bars for instance, labeled from $(1,2,3)$. Their gravitational potential energy is:

$$ U_{g,\,{\rm total}} = U_{g,\,1} + U_{g,\,2} + U_{g,\,3} \ne 3U_g $$

Each bar has a different gravitational potential energy so that the total gravitational potential energy cannot generally be factored in the "$3U_g$".

Likewise for the spring energy.